# Do or not do. Valueconverters in MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I'm looking for either confirmation/validation that what I'm doing follows the pattern and is best practice, or for somebody to verbally abuse me into submission!

If I'm doing Visibility binding on a [insert control here], I bind it to a property of type System.Windows.Visibility. I then set this value to Visible/Collapsed depending on business logic. One potential flaw in this is that my VM property is now tied directly to a type that I could see being abstracted out into a valueconverter. With that said, i've often read in MVVM discussions that ValueConverters shouldn't be used.

Can I get some feedback on this please?

Thanks!

SS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a fan of Converters, but specifically for reuse. It may be easy to do these conversions in a ViewModel, but what if you want the same conversion in many ViewModels or even 15 different applications?  If you limit yourself to the ViewModel only approach then you'll violate DRY.  That being said, I couldn't agree more that converters should not contain business logic and should not be used for "one off" solutions.

In the case you mentioned above, it would require a property of type Visibility in your ViewModel, which is a code smell to me.  IMHO, ViewModels should not reflect visual state, rather the Visual state of a View should react to the data state of the ViewModel.

Comment: "If you limit yourself to the VM only approach, then you'll violate DRY" - ftw. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think it's perfectly OK to use value converters for common UI scenarios (like binding the visibility to a boolean property). However, use them only for tasks that are purely UI-related: don't put any business logic in a converter, it doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 1):

It's a controversial topic but I sit in the camp where I think that you shouldn't use converters. The ViewModel is considered a "Converter on steroids" so you don't need any converters. 
(http://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples/browse_thread/thread/3fe270cd107f184f?pli=1)

If you use converters, you'll find that they end up everywhere in your project for the most mundane things. Ex: Want to display "3 customers" but have no plural if it's "1 customer". It's easy to do in a viewModel but get's tedious real fast in a converter.

Answer (score 1):

The view (XAML/WPF) and the ViewModel are responsible for different things. So if you are manipulating the data that the ViewModel serves up, it probably is best to do the conversion in the ViewModel. However if you need a conversion for purely a UI element then the view is the best place for it.

E.G. I would say that visibility is the responsibility of the ViewModel as there probably are some business rules around what is being displayed. However where you are changing a label plural-ness probably should be a UI responsibility. Besides you might decide to use Triggers rather than Converters. This should not be a concern for the ViewModel.

I do not believe you should not use something because a certain pattern is being used. It is a matter of using judgement on when to apply it or not and whether it makes the code testable, maintainable and is easily understood while providing a quality application.